# when passing multiple values to parameter comma gets encoded

Tags: javascript, jquery, encoding

I am using javascript and on click i change a parameter in url that has multiple values separated by comma.

When this url with multiple value param is loaded it looks like this

```
www.xyz.com/abc/result?param1 = ENSG00000115415&param2=56&param3=box&param4=7021,6092,6238,6324,7003
```

Than on this page 10 ajax calls are made, and as soon as those ajax calls are made , the comma in url gets encoded to %C and than % gets encoded to %25 againand again and because of that sometimes it hits 404.

How to stop this from encoding

Comment: Show us the code that is doing this.

Comment: code

    ('input.save').click(function(){
             base_url = $("#base_url").attr('href');
             if (count >= 2 && count <= 9) {
             datasets = datasets.slice(1);
             var newURL = base_url + '&param4='+datasets
             window.location = newURL;
    })

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the code nicely formatted

Comment: What is the problem with this encoding, its default behavior ?

Comment: The problem lies in this line of code. `window.location = newURL;` Please take a look at `escape` and `unescape` functions in javascript.

Comment: whats the solution

Comment: `the comma in url gets encoded to %C` - no, it gets encoded to `%2C`